# In HTML what are the default rules for element stacking order?

Tags: html, css, position

I am just trying to figure out the default HTML rules for element stacking order? Are there any stacking restrictions for element order for parents and children or sibling elements in a row? (or is it strictly the CSS that decides this?)

For the sake of clarity, I provide this example. In this example element A is stacked **over** element B: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyqBT.png)

As an example lets say a document like this with complex parents - children combinations,

```
<div id="A">
    <div id="B">
        <div id="D"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="C"></div>
</div>
```

I hope the question is clear enough.

UPDATE:
Thanks to the answer below I have established that for sibling elements by default HTML stacks elements that come after another element over previous elements when position is either fixed or absolute.

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/s8nzaoh9/

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by liitations... but it your example the structure makes no sense seing the desired result. ;)

Comment: You mean like the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)?

Comment: Dear both please see updates to the question that I hope have improved clarity. Yes I do mean stacking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends on how you put them. Basically, they will keep stacking unless you use some rules like z-index. It's like, the element with greater z-index will come over other elements. The element with greater z-index is always in front of an element with lower z-index.I don't know why there would be a reason not to use css to solve that problem.And you can stack as many elements as you want I think, it will all look messy, but to solve it, you need at least some css as far as I know.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style>
  #box1,#box2,#box3{
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   border:1px solid black;
   position: relative;
  }
  #box1{
   background-color: red;
   z-index: 10;

  }
  #box2{
   background-color: green;
   margin-top: -30px;
   z-index: 20;

  }
  #box3{
   background-color: blue;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="box1">
</div>

<div id="box2">
</div>

<div id="box3">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Try changing those values of z-index and see what happens

Comment: Hi Bourne96, thanks for your answer! By given no definite CSS attributes I meant that the CSS is unknown but can be anything! My question is targetted at the HTML, does the HTML limit which element can be stacked over another element or is it literally just the CSS that decides this?

Comment: It's just the way you put them, in which order, they are all going to stack, for example if it's inline element, it will keep going horizontally untill it reaches the max width, block will be stacking on top of each other. So, without css, there are no limitations as far as I know, it only depends in which order you put the elements.

Comment: Hi Bourne96, It looks like using your example by default they stack in the order they come in the HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/s8nzaoh9/ if they are all given the same z-Index and are positioned either in fixed or absolute. I will have to look deeper so see what he defaults are for parents and children elements.

Comment: Well they are, I didn't mean to stack them differently with that, just to show how they can overlap each other using z-index. If it's something positioned as absolute, it will look to the first parent margin as it's orientation, which is by default the body, if there is no some relative element.